# Issue with list.removeAll()

Tags: java, string

I'm using arraylists to find differences between two strings i.e `str2` and `str3`.
when i use the below code it works perfectly and returns the expected output.
but when I replace

```
str2 = #19, 6th cross, 7th main road, townname, cityname-560036
str3 = #19, 6th cross, 17th main road, townname, cityname-560036
```

the expected output should be : contents of al1: [1]

but the output I get is: contents of al1: `[]`

Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

here is my doPost method:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
            str2="Hello";
    str3="Hallo";
    System.out.println("-------");
    System.out.println("This is first string:"+""+str2);
    System.out.println("This is second string:"+""+str3);


    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList al1=new ArrayList(); 

      System.out.println("Initial size of al: " + al.size());

      // add elements to the array list
      for (int i = 0;i < str2.length(); i++)
        {
            al.add(str2.charAt(i));
        }
      System.out.println("Size of al after additions: " + al.size());

      // display the array list
      System.out.println("Contents of al: " + al);



      for (int i = 0;i < str3.length(); i++)
        {
            al1.add(str3.charAt(i));
        }

      System.out.println("Contents of al1: " + al1);

      System.out.println("Size of al1 after additions: " + al1.size());
        boolean hg=al1.removeAll(al);
        System.out.println("Remove All:"+hg);


      System.out.println("Contents of al: " + al);
      System.out.println("Contents of al1: " + al1);

}
```

Comment: what output you getting at this line "Remove All: " true of false ?

Comment: removeAll() uses regex. You want remove()

Comment: @Bohemian [List.removeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) does not use regex in any way.

Comment: @Bohemian Could you please explain the difference between removeAll() and remove().

Comment: @SudheepVk rather than asking a question you must search it before.

Comment: Both `replace()` and `replaceAll()` replace all occurrences in the String, but `replaceAll()` uses regex whereas `replace()` is just plain text. You want the plain text version, because if one of the characters has a special meaning in regex, eg `.`, your algorithm won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your problem, use the `String .split()` method

```
str2 = #19, 6th cross, 7th main road, townname, cityname-560036
str3 = #19, 6th cross, 17th main road, townname, cityname-560036

String[] s2 = str2.split(",");
String[] s3 = str3.split(",");

for (int i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
    al.add(s2[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < s3.length; i++) {
    al1.add(s2[i]);
}

al.retainAll(al1);

System.out.println("Size of a1 is " + a1.size());
```

Also, I think you want `retainAll()` and not `removeAll()`.  `retainAll()` is the one that returns a `boolean`, not `removeAll()`

Comment: Your code worked but I had to tweak it a bit to get the output I wanted

Comment: String str2 ="#19, 6th cross, 7th main road, townname, cityname-560036";
    String str3 = "#19, 6th cross, 27th main road, townname, cityname-560036";

    String[] s2 = str2.split(", ");
    String[] s3 = str3.split(", ");
    
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList al1=new ArrayList(); 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
        al.add(s2[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s3.length; i++) {
        al1.add(s3[i]);
    }

    al1.removeAll(al);

  System.out.println("Content of al1is " +al1);
response.sendRedirect("page1.jsp");

Comment: That's what we're all here for!

Answer (score 3):

You already have the character '1' here "#19" so when you call remove all, all the '1' are removed, including the one you were expecting to keep.
I think you should iterate through characters and extract the differences, otherwise the comparison won't be very accurate.

Comment: @Vlad I removed the '1' from '#19' and it works perfectly... but now how do I deal with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

From where i see: it looks like you need to compare tokens separated by comma. Create string lists of strs (split by ','), then you can remove similar strings and leftovers can be compared for differences.

Comment: Thank you and really appreaciate the help